# Javascript adding tooltip on over in selectbox that is created dynameclly

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, tooltip

I have a select box which i create dynamically with javascript i like to add a tooltip on over when
going over a mouse on the selected option so it just gives me the text value of the option.

This is how i create the selectbox ( simple )

```
var selectBoxDB = document.createElement("select");
    selectBoxDB .classList.add("form-control");
    selectBoxDB .id = "select_"+mydata["source_name"];
    selectBoxDB .style.width = "300px";
    td.appendChild(selectBoxDB );

 
for(var key in mydata.servers_list) {
    if (dbEntry.servers_list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        var option = new Option(key, key);
        option.title = key;                      
        selectBoxDB .appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

how to combine here or attach a function that when the select box created
when mouse over the selected option it will popup tooltip?

Comment: You are not going to do that with a select element.

Comment: how can i do it ? i saw allot of example on line they all complex , looking for something simple that i could plug to any select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a global mouse enter/leave listener to the `<select>` to display a tooltip with the current value.

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');

const showTooltip = (e) => {
  Object.assign(tooltip.style, {
    top: `${e.clientY + 8}px`,
    left: `${e.clientX + 8}px`
  });
  tooltip.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
    value: `${e.target.value}`,
    text: `${e.target.selectedOptions[0].text}`
  }, null, 2);
  tooltip.classList.add('show');
  e.target.setAttribute('title', e.target.selectedOptions[0].text);
};

const hideTooltip = (e) => {
  tooltip.classList.remove('show');
};

const attachListeners = (observeable) => {
  observeable.addEventListener('mouseenter', showTooltip);
  observeable.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideTooltip);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.observeable').forEach(attachListeners);
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: thin solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hello World</div>
<select class="observeable">
  <option value="apple">One</option>
  <option value="banana">Two</option>
  <option value="carrot">Three</option>
  <option value="date">Four</option>
  <option value="eggplant">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i dont need tooltip when you see all options
Only when selected .. the one and single option that was selected i want to see it on the tooltip , again when it allready selected ...

Comment: @user63898 ok, I updated the response. Not sure if you want an actual "tooltip" or just want to update the title.